# This application does not exist (app_id=xxx)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was unable to upload to an AppEngine as `appcfg` was telling me :

> This application does not exist (app_id=u'xxx').

I was only a developer on the AppEngine, so as I was just testing I created a new AppEngine where I was the owner but I still get the same message on a newly created AppEngine.

Comment: Are you running a recent version of the SDK? Earlier versions cannot upload to high-replication apps.

Comment: Wooble - No it didn't, it said my actual AppId - I just didn't want to post it.

Comment: This happened to me when I used the wrong email address (as username).  Strange not to get "permission denied" or something.

Comment: Anybody know how to use other login details if you've used the wrong one?

Comment: I think you need the --no_cookies option

Comment: After some SERIOUS digging I found the following worked for me: `appcfg.py -e <email_address> --passin --no_cookies update .`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The fix I found was to add the parameter `--no_cookies`:

```sh
appcfg.py update --no_cookies MyProjectDirectory/
```

This can happen when you upload AppEngine applications from different Google accounts on the same computer.

Comment: to be honest, i have no clue. the way i was able to find my answer was by uploading my app from my Mac OS X (thank god i have linux mac and windows). that worked, and then looking at the appengine GUI they have for Mac, i found the command they used in the console, which included "--no_cookies". so perhaps if you ran into similar issues in the future, this is one approach to getting the answer

Comment: You can also remove the .appcfg_cookies file and then it will replace it with a valid version after you enter your password.

Comment: This worked, I was using two different IDs to upload different application i.e on two different accounts, so in terminal my previous id was stored and then when i created my GAE app on second account, i was not able to update it because of previous account cookies. This worked... Great!!!

Comment: I have an alternation solution - in the Google App Engine Launcher select from the menu Control > Clear Deployment Credential. Then when you click Deploy it will take you through the auth flow again and you can select the correct account.

Answer (score 12):

You have to log in in your gae account and create an application before you upload it, and your app_id has to have the same name as you app. You can't just upload it.

So go [here](https://appengine.google.com/), create your app, for example "example_app" and set the app_id=example_app and everything should work :)

Comment: "set the app_id=example_app" refers to editing `app.yaml` and adjusting the `application` field appropriately.

Comment: yep, thanks for the clarification, I maybe was not explicit enough.

Comment: Hi, Hassek and @Xion. Thanks for answering but I've already done this. I guess I wasn't clear enough when I said "I created a new AppEngine " what I meant was I created a new application on appengine. See this [screenshot](https://docs.google.com/a/appogee.co.uk/uc?id=0B6EKPsCXg8XzZjMyODM3NDYtNmMwNi00ZjUwLWIyYzYtZDE1MzhhNjQ5MDdj&export=download&hl=en_GB), I am unable to upload my code to either of the second or third items in the list. Both apps exists and I can view the dashboard, and eveything you would expect but I can't upload to it. Yet I can upload the same code to the first in the list

Comment: I can't see the screenshot :(, and that is pretty odd. I remember once when I first created an app that it took a while to begin serving but that is just a guess

Comment: Does it work now? [screenshot](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B6EKPsCXg8XzZjMyODM3NDYtNmMwNi00ZjUwLWIyYzYtZDE1MzhhNjQ5MDdj&hl=en_GB) ... Yea it is odd, never had anything like this before. I have been trying periodically to upload as another post I read said that it once took a few hours for them but I've had no luck so far...

Answer (score 5):

The same problem occurs with the Java/Eclipse plugin version of App Engine. The 404 happens when you're logged in to the wrong Google account from within the plugin. In that case, look at the bottom-left of Eclipse to see what account you're currently using.

Regarding the Python command line updater, if your cookies indicate that you're logged in to a Google account that doesn't have access to the application you're updating, then that would explain why ignoring those cookies by using "appcfg.py update --nocookies" fixes it.

Comment: oh. no wonder. i never knew about the whole google account checking the cookies before updating. thanks, that explains things

Answer (score 4):

This is really old, so I wouldn't be surprised if this isn't picked up by the poster, but I wanted to ensure that I have a reference for the next time I have the issue.

I had this issue. My problem ended up being that I had not invited the user that I was authenticating as to be a developer on the project. In fact I had just created the user and not even logged on yet.

I logged on to the google infrastructure as the new user, then added the new user as a developer on the application. I was then able to upload the app.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to upload to the app this morning (first time i've tried since Friday) and it just worked (first time...!)

No idea what the issue was as I haven't done any work on this over the weekend so everything should have been the same as it was on Friday.

Comment: It should have been an indexing of some sort. It sometimes happens and takes a long while

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message trying to make the first deployment of a Python Application using a Google Apps account.

In my case the problem was caused by the fact that my 2-way authentication is enabled.

With 2-way authentication enabled you need to generate an authentication password in your Google Account Management Application and use it to do the deployments.

Answer (score 1):

this way worked:

1. modified the app.yaml to specify the application: some_id
2. python appcfg.py update ../some_application/server/python

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by editing my app.yaml file to have the correct application name. In the app.yaml file where it says 'application:[insert app name here]', I had to change the [insert app name here] part. I'm not sure why the name was wrong, but I do remember toying around with it before while attempting to fix a different bug. The way I figured out the proper name was to go to my applications in my GAE admin console and look to see what the app's name was there. Hope this helps anyone else that runs into this same problem :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `--oauth2` make sure that you are logged into the correct account when generating the token.

Comment: how do you tell which account it thinks you're logged into?

Answer (score 1):

```
appcfg.py --no_cookies --oauth2 --email=myemail --noauth_local_webserver  update .
```

I navigated to my app engine directory folder and ran the above command. This deployed it successfully from the command line for me (Mac OSX terminal)--although I still couldn't deploy from app engine launcher. I believe Launcher still thinks I'm running off port 8080. However, running `dev_appserver.py --port=11080 .`doesn't fix this issue for me-- what ended up solving it was just removing the directory from the app engine launcher then just re-adding it.

Comment: (This also helped me resolve --- begin server output ---
You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u's~blah-project').
--- end server output ---)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to use the project id from the google app engine console instead of the project name in app.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Posting Ric Moore's comment in the selected answer because that is a valid answer and it worked in my case (and hopefully it helps someone else having the same issue spot it quickly).

> I have an alternation solution - in the Google App Engine Launcher select from the menu Control > Clear Deployment Credential. Then when you click Deploy it will take you through the auth flow again and you can select the correct account. - Ric Moore

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I simply needed to run 'gcloud app create' for this project within the console console. [Screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/EOvsmkWl2)

Previously I don't think this step was needed.