# Google App Engine : this application does not exist

Tags: google-app-engine

When i deploy my application in GAE , i get this error

```
      This application does not exist (app_id=u'qsse-ss').
```

scenario is that this application is already deployed to GAE by some other user , now i have made some changes and i want to update in GAE, so now when i right click on my app in eclipse and go to "deploy to appengine " it gives me this error

Am i doing something wrong , whats the correct way of doing it

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was different name which i changed from rightClick project ->appenginesettings->ApplicationId .

this name should be same in your google account

Comment: Isn't that exactly what my answer was?

Answer (score 28):

That happened to me as well when I provided a username that wasn't an owner/developer, and even specifying a different account with -e or --email didn't work. What fixed was this:

```
appcfg.py update . --no_cookies
```

(same as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10004722)

Answer (score 7):

You have to login under developer or owner to deploy application. This is bottom left icon in eclipse.

Also check your application name. If id of application correct and user you login has role owner/developer for this application - you will deploy.

Answer (score 4):

You have to make sure that application name in your GAE local client matches the one in your Google account. Check the app.yaml file to make sure that the name of application matches there as well.

Comment: thanks , but i couldnt find the file .yaml  .. any suggestion

Answer (score 3):

That also happend to me when I change the email to create new appid for goagent.

My solution is delete cookie file in the server directory:

```
rm server/.appcfg_cookies
```

then, everything is ok!

Comment: Where is the server directory. I can't find it?

Comment: That's the home directory:  

    $ pwd
    /Users/januarvs
    $ ls -l .appcfg_cookies 
    -rw-------  1 januarvs  staff  126 Feb 28 14:59 .appcfg_cookies
    $

Answer (score 2):

Deleted `.appcfg_oauth2_tokens` `c:/usrs/etc`  worked for me after a long overdue upgrade to python27.

Answer (score 1):

At least as of 2017-06-22, it's not enough to create a cloud project. You have to go to the [App Engine section of cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine) and choose a language. When it's done saying "Preparing your App Engine services..." then you can deploy.

Comment: Where can I find the description supporting this? In official sources?

Comment: I don't know; I discovered this through trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the oauth2 token file ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens or specifying a different token store file file with the flag "--oauth2_credential_file" might be a permanent solution. MacOSX GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app does not let you change this flag/path when you push the deploy button.

```
appcfg.py --oauth2_credential_file=~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_myappid
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same error message:

> This application does not exist (project_id=u'xxxx-123456'). To create an
>   App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud app create" in
>   your console.

I solved it by executing below command:

```
gcloud app create
```

It will create app inside your project and assign selected region.