# Where does Android Studio hide upload permissions for an app engine project?

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I had a working app engine project (Java) which I had created from a template some time ago. The upload always worked fine and I don't remember that I had entered credentials when I set it up. Well, probably I did at some point, but I don't remember what the mechanism was.

Now I switched the project to another app engine project which also has a different admin user. I changed  to the new application-name-000 in appengine-web.xml and started the upload, but gradle/appengineUpdate keeps telling me this:

```
Oct 20, 2014 10:06:35 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=application-name-000&version=2&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'application-name-000').
```

Sure the application does not exist, because it's a new project for app engine ;-) I tried to set version 2 to version 1 temporarily which doesn't seem to be the problem. I googled and found out it seems to be a permission problem, but I can't find any hint what I need to do or where I can set the new permissions in Android Studio.

What is the process? Will I need to copy some key from app engine into the project, or where can I set my username/oauth whatever in Android Studio?

Comment: What makes you think this was a permissions problem? The error message is quite explicit: the application "application-name-000" does not exist. Have you created that application in the App Engine console? And why have you appended "000" to the app name?

Comment: As Daniel pointed out... just create your app in console.developers.google.com, get a name for it, and edit your app.yaml to go to that app

Comment: application-name-000 is my app-id [I just made it opaque because I didn't want to post it here]. I have created the app on app engine and it exists there under the exact same name as it does in my app.yaml [which is appengine-web.xml here as I am using Java]. I believe it's a permissions problem because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407955/google-app-engine-this-application-does-not-exist and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039200/this-application-does-not-exist-app-id-xxx and other posts I have found.

Comment: @Patrice why do you assume I can just create a project and upload? This would mean I can do a URL scan and overwrite anybody's project. I am sure Google did not implement it that way. There must be a way for Android Studio to know it is your project, which IMO can only work using credentials, a key or oauth.

Comment: because that's how it works. Go to console.developers.google.com, create new project, that'll give you an ID. Then put that ID in your app.yaml (or appengine-web.xml).  Normally you have a credential asked whenever you upload (using command line or app engine launcher... in some other cases it is a config file with your project). Maybe your android studio is "stuck" on a previous account that doesn't have permissions to your new project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found out how to fix this. And yes, it is a permissions problem (see proof further below).

Android Studio uses oauth to connect to the project to app engine. When you install Android Studio and then create the project the first time, it creates the following file in your home directory:

```
.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java (in Windows this is under c:\Users\{Username}\)
```

This is a file with no name and just an extension. This file contains the token to connect and upload to app engine.

If the oauth user changes, Android Studio uses the wrong credentials and the upload fails.

To solve the problem:

1. Delete the file.
2. Call appengineUpdate from the *command line* (!), not from the menu (in Windows, you typically open the Terminal from within Android Studio and from within your module, then enter

   ..\gradlew appengineUpdate
3. It starts the update and due to the missing file, Android Studio pops open your browser where you select your Google user and give permissions. You then receive a code.
4. Copy that code and paste it into the Terminal. There is no input box or anything. The command line just stops and says *nothing*. Paste your code there and press enter.

A new file will then be created for you, the token saved to the file, and your project should upload fine.

The hint to the file I found here http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8300 and the hint how to copy the code was here http://code.google.com/p/qt-google-calendar/issues/detail?id=2 (awful, Google).

That it was a permissions problem could be seen, when I changed my build.gradle file:

```
appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
}
```

oauth2 = true produced this error message:

```
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=...&version=2&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'...').
```

while oauth2 = false produced this one:

```
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=...&version=2&
401 Unauthorized
Must authenticate first.
```

What do we learn? Never trust an error messages, no matter how explicit it seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the password on the first account and when you try to run appengineUpdate it will prompt you for new account details.