# This application does not exist (app_id) in Java Netbeans Glassfish web application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans, glassfish

I am a new programmer trying to deploy my Java web application to a web host for the first time. I started trying to do it with Jelastic but I need file storage, not just a .jar file, and it looks like you have to pay a LOT to upgrade.

If you know of a way I can upload my application and also store a single .png (image) file so my application can overwrite it by accessing the URL please let me know. I don't mind paying X money for a host but $150 or whatever is crazy.

In the meantime I found that Google App Engine lets you upload a Java application. I have been trying to do this for maybe 3 hours.

I am stuck with the error:

```
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=animelist1&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'animelist1').
```

I have checked that I am logged in under the correct Google account (no others, and rebooted and used CCleaner to clear my browser cache), that I have an empty project in Google App Engine called "animelist1" and have checked that my application is called "animelist1" with the appengine-web.xml with "animelist".

I am using the netbeans plugin to deploy to Google. I have the correct email set there.

There are many people with this issue who fixed it the same way. However as I am a beginner I am unable to figure out how to do this method. The method is

[This application does not exist (app_id=xxx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039200/this-application-does-not-exist-app-id-xxx)

[Google App Engine : this application does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407955/google-app-engine-this-application-does-not-exist)

(and many others with similar answers)

The method is "appcfg.py update --no_cookies MyProjectDirectory/"  or "appcfg.py update . --no_cookies"

Can you please assist me in doing this?

I have located appcfg.py at

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine
```

there is another one at

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools
```

there is also a appcfg_java.py here but we can come to that later if need be.

I have tried using the Google Cloud SDK Shell (which looks like the cmd console) to navigate to the directory and type those commands. This opens the file in a text file and doesn't seem to do anything else.

I believe I may have to find the appcfg relevant to my application/project (but I'm not sure).  When I do a computer search for the file I get 8 files with that name returned:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RnaM.jpg)

All I want to do really is upload my Java Glassfish web application, then upload a .png file so I can point my application to it (it will overwrite the file).

I thought about changing my application to run on Tomcat because I thought I saw there was a free Java host that allows tomcat. That was several hours ago now because I have been headbutting this thing so maybe I should just abort and try that instead. Or if you know of a host that doesn't cost $150+ let me know. I don't know why they said they cost that, I thought you could host really cheaply.

Please help, thankyou!!!!

The full code of my error is below. I don't know why there is an error about System Java Compiler, I just checked my environment after messing it up, saw it hadn't saved, then rebooted, and now it is saved. I have a JAVA_HOME system variable set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40 and my Path system variable is 
    C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40

(maybe I don't need both, not sure). I have nothing else set there, nothing in User Variables though I will double check if that is needed.

Here is my full error log:

```
********************************************************
There is a new version of the SDK available.
-----------
Latest SDK:
Release: 1.9.19
Timestamp: Thu Feb 19 23:57:40 GMT 2015
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Your SDK:
Release: 1.9.18
Timestamp: Thu Feb 12 19:30:16 GMT 2015
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Please visit https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads for the latest SDK.
********************************************************
Reading application configuration data...
Apr 20, 2015 6:51:40 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:/Users/J/Documents/NetBeansProjects/g5/target/animelist1-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Apr 20, 2015 6:51:40 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:/Users/J/Documents/NetBeansProjects/g5/target/animelist1-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF/web.xml


Beginning interaction for module default...
Apr 20, 2015 6:51:40 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=animelist1&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'animelist1').
This is try #0
Apr 20, 2015 6:51:40 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=animelist1&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'animelist1').
This is try #1
Apr 20, 2015 6:51:41 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=animelist1&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'animelist1').
This is try #2
Apr 20, 2015 6:51:41 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=animelist1&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'animelist1').
This is try #3
0% Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8900677438454325367.tmp'
5% Scanning for jsp files.
8% Compiling jsp files.

Error Details:
Apr 20, 2015 6:51:42 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
INFO: Built File: \index.jsp


java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.
Unable to update app: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.
Please see the logs [C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg6599854602413633444.log] for further information.
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem but with python. It had worked flawlessly up until a few months ago. None of the solutions I've come across work. I've tried clearing the cache in my browsers, switching browsers, using the GAE app launcher, command line, updating to the latest SDK. Nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

*I have an empty project in Google App Engine called "animelist1"*

If you mean that you've used the SDK set up a local project, then you might have missed a step. When you visit http://appengine.google.com/ , does "animelist1" appear in the list of your applications? If not, you'll need to click the `Create Application` button (and hope that someone else hasn't already used that appid).

Answer (score 0):

No project with ID 'animelist1' currently exists, but this ID is not available (it could exist in the past, but was deleted). If you already created the project your App ID is the same as Project ID, not Project name. If you didn't yet create the project, create one either in the old App Engine console as suggested by Dave or as per [manual](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating).

Answer (score 0):

**This is an credentials issue in most cases when you download code from already exsit project.**

1. Make sure you have only one google account login your default browser.
2. Go to your `lib/appengine-java-sdk-<version>/bin/` and run:
   `appcfg --no_cookies  update <project-dir>`

**Note:** early appcfg version command may like :
`appcfg update --no_cookies  <project-dir>`