# Unable to upload an application via Google App Engine (from an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine)

Tags: google-app-engine, web, web-applications, webapp2

I am just beginning to learn about the basics of web serving, and I've run into difficulty uploading an application online via the Google App Engine.

***What worked without problems***

My machine is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. First, I downloaded the Google App Engine SDK for Python which I then installed into the directory `~/Desktop/web_development/google_appengine`.

Next, I implemented an application which displays a short message. Specifically, I created the directory `~/Desktop/web_development/unit_01/homework_01` in which I saved the files `helloworld.py` and `app.yaml`; these two files were created according to the instructions on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld.

After navigating into `~/Desktop/web_development`, I was able to successfully test the application via the terminal command:

`$ google_appengine/dev_appserver.py unit_01/homework_01/`

(In other worlds, I could successfully open http://localhost:8080/ in my browser.)

***Where the problem occurred:***

When I run the command

`$ google_appengine/appcfg.py -A ludata-rabota update unit_01/homework_01/`

I receive the following output:

`02:45 PM Application: ludata-rabota (was: None); version: 1
02:45 PM Host: appengine.google.com
02:45 PM 
Starting update of app: ludata-rabota, version: 1
02:45 PM Getting current resource limits.
02:45 PM Scanning files on local disk.
Error 404: --- begin server output ---
This application does not exist (app_id=u'ludata-rabota').
--- end server output ---`

***Feedback request***

If you could offer any feedback as to how to resolve this issue, I would be very grateful.

Comment: follow a tutorial and you will see you missed a key step of creating the app in the console, which is the error is breing printed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google App Engine : this application does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407955/google-app-engine-this-application-does-not-exist)

Comment: a trivial search on your error shows many answers covering this.

Answer (score 0):

These conditions must be met:

1. Your app directory must have the same name as the app.
2. Your app name must be unique for appengine.
3. Your app name must be in your `app.yaml`

It looks like you didn't name your app directory the same name as your application name. If you follow the above listed conditions then it will work.