# GAE/J This application does not exist (app_id=u'application-id')

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, maven-gae-plugin

I use maven-gae-plugin to deploy my app, it works find until i decide to deploy it to another app-id under different Google account. i met the "This applciation does not exist" problem.

I found there are already some answers in StackOverflow, but was for python, i'm using GAE/J.
I think i know the root cause, we should delete the "cache" in local, which stored my previous username/password, but what are these cache? and where are them?

Or there are other ways to avoid this, i've tried so many ways but none works, so frustrating.

Thanks in advance.
I'm on Window7, GAE1.6.3

Edit: the python version answer is here:
[This application does not exist (app_id=xxx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039200/this-application-does-not-exist-app-id-xxx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new option `--no_cookies` (documented [here](https://devsite.googleplex.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Command_Line_Arguments)) of the `appcfg.sh` tool to prevent loading the cookies. Or you could delete the cookie/cache file which at least in Linux is stored in `~/.java/.userPrefs/com/google/appengine/tools/admin/prefs.xml`.

I have no experience with the maven-gae-plugin, but it seems you would need to modify the `EngineGoalBase.java` file to allow the new parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your input, i can't find the "prefs.xml" file because i'm on Windows. About the --no_cookies option, i even can't verify it. could you please help? i use: appcfg update . --no_cookies --proxy=xx.xx.xx.xx:8080 but it always give me connection time out exception(i'm behind a proxy and the proxy server i provided is correct)

Comment: The options go before the command. That is, the command you need to execute is "appcfg.sh --no_cookies --proxy=xx.xx.xx.xx:8080 update ."

Comment: Sorry, maybe appcfg java version on windows does not support the "--no_cookies, or GAE1.6.3 does not support this? it just gives me: "Bad argument: unknown option: --no_cookies"

Answer (score 2):

I'm running app engine using maven plugin. On Windows you need to delete the file in user home dir. The file name is something like **.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java**

Answer (score -1):

What IDE are you using? If it's Eclipse you need to make sure you're logged into your Google account in Eclipse before trying to deploy, or you will get that error.

Alternatively, make sure your new Google account is authorized to deploy by the admin of the GAE account AND the web admin if you get your Google account through a company/organization. For example my school gmail account does not allow me to be an admin for GAE.

Comment: As i said i use maven-gae-plugin to deploy my app, not Google Plugin for Eclipse. Anyway thanks for the input.