# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'appengine-try-python-flask'

Tags: google-app-engine

I got the above error when trying the steps in https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine, specifically, step 5.3:

```
% dev_appserver.py appengine-try-python-flask
```

I used the "Download your code" button to download the sample code, and ran the above cmd there. The unzipped dir does not have a file or dir named 'appengine-try-python-flask', so the error is legitimate. My question is: What is this file and how do I get it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue (on OS X 10.9.2). dev_appserver.py requires at least one argument which should be the yaml_path. So just replace:

`dev_appserver.py appengine-try-python-flask`

With:

`dev_appserver.py app.yaml`

Or whatever your environment config YAML file is called.

Also your next question may be about step 6 when deploying your app; you'll have to replace:

`appcfg.py -A grey-goose-777 update appengine-try-python`

With:

`appcfg.py -A grey-goose-777 update app.yaml`

Jonathan

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. Using "app.yaml" works.
When I tried to publish the code, I got this error:
  This application does not exist (app_id=u'rising-ocean-576').
And the solution for that can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039200/this-application-does-not-exist-app-id-xxx), i.e.g,
  `% appcfg.py ... update --no_cookies app.yaml`